# Rationale for security lockout after changing a password

Tags: account-security, account-lockout

I was recently locked out of an account (for 30 minutes), **not** for failing a certain number of attempts at a password, but instead **for changing the password** after answering security questions.

What do you think the purpose of this security mechanism is?

I was under the impression that the only purpose of a lockout was to prevent brute force password attacks. Since the purpose of security questions is to prove identity without a password, I can't fathom why a lockout would be used in this situation.

Comment: Possibly to give the account holder time to contact support if the change is unauthorized?

Comment: Can you give us more context? Was this an app, web service? Public, internal corp? May make a difference, but it does not seem like a general practice.

Comment: It was an external federal website, so I suspect they are being overly cautious as usual. I have had the account for years, I think this is new. I also got an email asking if the action was unauthorized so I bet that is it, though I have gotten such emails before from other sites without being locked out. It did specifically say that the lockout was due to the password change though and that is what I thought was weird. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 2):

I am with @Cowthulhu about the cooldown time.

Lastpass uses something similar for their recovery access: you can designate someone as trusted, that person can request an access to your password vault, but will have to wait a predefined time (predefined by you, from nothing to a few days) to give you time to revoke the access. In the meantime you recieve an email stating that a request was done.

Have you received a message from the site owner right after the change with some similar information ("*your password was changed but the user is locked for 30 minutes, if it was not you contact us during that timeframe so that we revert the change*")? Since you asked the question - I guess not, but maybe this is buried somewhere in the informational email.

Comment: I believe it was worded similar to that, though the email I got was pretty generic, and said nothing about the lockout, just that the password had been changed. The lockout warning was on the website itself after I tried to log back in.